# Optimize selection between dates

Tags: sql-server, optimization, query-optimization

My stored procedure performs really badly. Any suggestions on how to improve it ?

```
 select  t2.ID,
    t2.Transactions,
    t2.StartTime,
    t2.EndTime,
    t2.Good,
    t2.OK,
    t2.Bad,
    t1.PID,
    t1.PName
from(
select distinct ID,
     max([PID]) as MaxPID, 
     min([DATE_S]) as StartTime,
     max([DATE_S]) as EndTime,  
     count([ID_P]) as Transactions,
     coalesce(count(case when [STATUS] = 0 then 1 end), 0)  as Good,
     coalesce(count(case when [STATUS] = 1 then 1 end), 0)  as Warning,
     coalesce(count(case when [STATUS] > 1 then 1 end), 0)  as Bad
 from  [dbo].[Table1]
 where CONVERT(date, [DATE_S]) between CONVERT(date, @StartDate) and 
 CONVERT(date, @EndDate)
 group by ID) t2
 LEFT join [dbo].[Table2] t1 on t2.MaxPID = t1.[PID] 
order by ID desc
```

would really appreciate any tips.

Comment: `DISTINCT` over something that was `GROUP`ed already doesn't make much sense. Also, I doubt `COUNT()` works the way you think it works. You'll probably want to use `SUM()` instead for this. (And since I'm at it anyway, it's kind of confusing to use `t1` as an alias for `Table2` (and vice versa))

Answer (score 0):

A couple of assumptions - your @startdate and @enddate are dates (no time component) and your database records are datetime. Also assume there is an index on date_s, but it is not being used because you are not using it directly in the where clause. The way to handle this is to leave the date_s as is, and then use in your between clause the @startdate (which will be midnight on the day of the start, and @endDate+1 which will be the following midnight.

Of course this might find a row from the following day that started at exactly midnight, if that the case then use next day-1second or something similar. But unlikely to be an issue.

The where clause:

```
where DATE_S between @StartDate and dateadd(d,1,@EndDate)
```

Comment: Actually, midnight dates are quite likely to be an issue. If any dates are added with no time, then they will show as midnight. Instead of subtracting 1 second, don't use between, instead do Where Date_S >= CONVERT(date, @StartDate) and Date_S < dateadd(d,1,CONVERT(date, @EndDate))  Note <, for the end date, not <=

Comment: @DancingFool Yes depends on the scenario. Like I said - some assumptions where made! If manually added then likely no time, if added automatically when a transaction is added then unlikely. But good idea to just swap to >= and <. Thinking back that's how I've always coded it too.

Answer (score 0):

try Something like this :

```
declare @StartDateDt as datetime=cast(@StartDate as date);
declare @EndDateDt as datetime=cast(EndDate as date);

With tmp as (
select ID, 
     max(PID) as MaxPID, 
     min(DATE_S) as StartTime,
     max(DATE_S) as EndTime,  
     count(ID_P) as Transactions,
     sum(case when STATUS = 0 then 1 else 0 end)  as Good,
     sum(case when STATUS = 1 then 1 else 0 end)  as Warning,
     sum(case when STATUS > 1 then 1 else 0 end)  as Bad
 from  dbo.Table1
 where cast(DATE_S as date) between @StartDateDt  and @EndDateDt
 group by ID
)
select T2.*, T1.PID, T1.PName  
from tmp T1
LEFT join dbo.Table2 T2 on T1.MaxPID = T2.PID
order by T1.ID desc
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select ID,
     max([PID]) as MaxPID, 
     min([DATE_S]) as StartTime,
     max([DATE_S]) as EndTime,  
     count([ID_P]) as Transactions,
     coalesce(count(case when [STATUS] = 0 then 1 end), 0)  as Good,
     coalesce(count(case when [STATUS] = 1 then 1 end), 0)  as Warning,
     coalesce(count(case when [STATUS] > 1 then 1 end), 0)  as Bad int #tmpResult
 from  [dbo].[Table1]
 where CONVERT(date, [DATE_S]) between CONVERT(date, @StartDate) and 
 CONVERT(date, @EndDate)
 group by ID

SELECT  t2.ID,
    t2.Transactions,
    t2.StartTime,
    t2.EndTime,
    t2.Good,
    t2.OK,
    t2.Bad,
    t1.PID,
    t1.PName
FROM #tmpResult t2
 LEFT join [dbo].[Table2] t1 on t2.MaxPID = t1.[PID] 
order by ID desc
```

Comment: Distinct and group are not necessary in same time ;)

Answer (score 0):

I assume `[DATE_S]` contain `datetime` value(date and time)

`@StartDate` and `@EndDate` are datetime datatype but contain only date value.

So add 1 day in @EndDate

```
set @EndDate=DateADd(day,1,@EndDate)



    select  t2.ID,
        t2.Transactions,
        t2.StartTime,
        t2.EndTime,
        t2.Good,
        t2.OK,
        t2.Bad,
        t1.PID,
        t1.PName
    from(

    select  ID,
         max([PID]) as MaxPID, 
         min([DATE_S]) as StartTime,
         max([DATE_S]) as EndTime,  
         count([ID_P]) as Transactions,
         coalesce(count(case when [STATUS] = 0 then 1 end), 0)  as Good,
         coalesce(count(case when [STATUS] = 1 then 1 end), 0)  as Warning,
         coalesce(count(case when [STATUS] > 1 then 1 end), 0)  as Bad
     from  [dbo].[Table1]
     where [DATE_S]>=@StartDate and [DATE_S]<=@EndDate
     group by ID
    ) t2
     LEFT join [dbo].[Table2] t1 on t2.MaxPID = t1.[PID] 
order by ID desc

Create non Clustered index ix_Date on Table1(DATE_S)include(PID,ID_P,STATUS)
```

You can tell the indexes of both table so that my index is corrected accordingly.